# TFS | VSTS - Custom Build Task execution cannot find VstsTaskSdk.psd1

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

My team is working on a TFS/VSTS custom build task that utilizes the [vsts-task-lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib).

We followed the instructions on [this github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Consuming.md#package-the-sdk-with-the-task) to include it with your custom task.

I have the vsts-task-lib installed locally for interactive testing, and that is executing ok. I am able to get the extension uploaded and installed into my VSTS account/project.

However, when I line everything up and execute a Release on VSTS, I get the following:

```
2016-12-22T21:41:27.4700501Z ##[section]Starting: ApprendaDeploy 

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5110766Z ==============================================================================

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z Task         : Deploy App on Apprenda

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z Description  : This task deploys your application onto ACP

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z Version      : 0.1.0

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z Author       : Apprenda

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z Help         : Replace with markdown to show in help

2016-12-22T21:41:27.5120761Z ==============================================================================

2016-12-22T21:41:27.8483971Z ##[error]File not found: 'C:\a\_tasks\ApprendaDeploy_fb765e50-c211-11e6-9471-0d5c99017b97\0.1.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1'

2016-12-22T21:41:27.8553964Z ##[section]Finishing: ApprendaDeploy
```

I'm using vsts-task-lib v0.8.0 and my task root file directory looks like this:

```
|-- apprendaDeploy <task root>
  |----- ps_modules
     |----- VstsTaskSDK
        |----- 0.8.0
            |------ <corresponding sdk files, including VstsTaskSdk.psd1>
  |----- common.ps1
  |----- deploy.ps1
  |----- icon.png
  |----- task.json
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the version in your path? Should be `...\VstsTaskSDK\0.8.0\VstsTaskSdk.psd1`. Or try moving the SDK files out of the 0.8.0 folder so that it's sitting in the VstsTaskSDK folder.

Comment: Can you share that extension files on the OneDrive?

Comment: remove the version altogether. it should be `ps_modules/vststasksdk/vststasksdk.psd1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to move the SDK files to `...\VstsTaskSdk\*` rather than them being in a version specific folder. I ran into the same issue and resolved it this way.

Comment: Do you know if you can install to modules path and autoload or has to be copied into each task? I am struggling to find good documentation on the new library

Comment: How did you configure that?

Comment: You need to copy it into each task.

Comment: This is also a part of [this tutorial](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dev-ops-vsts-custom-build-task-extension)

Comment: I wish this worked for me... I've gotten none of my tasks to work. And I followed these instructions to a T