# VSTS extension can't find sdk

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I've gone through several examples, but despite my efforts every time I execute my realease task it can't locate the sdk:

> [error]System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The term 'Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I've tried with the SDK under the task root per the advice of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292533/tfs-vsts-custom-build-task-execution-cannot-find-vststasksdk-psd1). I've also tried it with the version number removed from the path.

```
|-- task root
  |----- ps_modules
     |----- VstsTaskSDK
        |----- 0.10.0
            |------ <corresponding sdk files, including VstsTaskSdk.psd1>
  |----- deploy.ps1
  |----- icon.png
  |----- task.json
```

I've also tried it with the sdk folder one level above the task as I've seen that work. Again, tried that with both the version number present and removed.

```
  |-- root
    |-- task root      
      |----- deploy.ps1
      |----- icon.png
      |----- task.json
    |-- sdk      
      |----- ps_modules
      |----- VstsTaskSDK
        |----- 0.10.0
          |------ <corresponding sdk files, including VstsTaskSdk.psd1>
```

Then I tried messing around with the files stanza in the vss-extension.json file, including sdk, or sdk/ps_modules/VstsTaskSdk, etc. 15 permutations I've tried and no success.

When I create the package I am running the following cmd from the extension root (not sure if relevant):

```
tfx extension create --manifest-globs .\vss-extension.json
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

> UPDATE

I have not been able to resolve this so I simplified my task for testing purposes. My task now contains just the sdk; no parameters, and just two cmdlets in my powershell:

```
Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation $MyInvocation
Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation $MyInvocation
```

My Task.json:

```
{
  "id": "<myguid>",
  "name": "VstsSdkTest",
  "friendlyName": "VstsSdkTest",
  "description": "A Test Task to troubleshoot vststasksdk issue",
  "helpMarkDown": "",
  "category": "Deploy",
  "visibility": [
    "Deploy"
  ],
  "instanceNameFormat": "VstsSdkTest",
  "author": "<myAuthor>",
  "version": {
    "Major": 0,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Patch": 1
  },  
  "execution": {
    "Powershell3": {
      "target": "VstsTaskSDKTest.ps1"
    }
  }
}
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- VstsSdkTest 
  |----- VstsTaskSDKTest.ps1
  |----- icon.png
  |----- task.json
  |----- ps_modules     
    |----- VstsTaskSDK
      |----- <corresponding sdk files, including VstsTaskSdk.psd1>
```

Even with this simplified task every time it executes (on the hosted agent) it cannot find the SDK. It seems to be looking for the SDK in a folder under the task that correlates to the task version number.

```
2017-10-24T20:39:08.9599715Z ##[error]File not found: 'd:\a\_tasks\VstsSdkTest_<myGuid>\0.1.1\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1'
```

Comment: Based on your answer (deleted), do you solve this issue after approving the scope change?

Comment: No, I thought the issue was resolved so I posted that answer. Further investigation revealed the issue is still occuring so I deleted it.

Comment: Could you make a package for all the files with folder structure and share it here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to me not understanding I had to update the version number in the task.json file whenever I moved the vststasksdk folder. I assumed that I just needed to update the vss-extension.json version because it contains the file stanza. Not the case. The final folder structure that worked for me was having the sdk stored in a folder at the task root.

```
|-- VstsSdkTest 
  |----- VstsTaskSDKTest.ps1
  |----- icon.png
  |----- task.json
  |----- ps_modules     
    |----- VstsTaskSDK
      |----- <corresponding sdk files, including VstsTaskSdk.psd1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using PowerShell and call SDK command, so using **PowerShell3** instead (not PowerShell).

Part code of task.json file:

```
"execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
      "target": "deploy.ps1",
      "argumentFormat": ""
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my task,json, did not resolve.

Comment: please check my update. I tried to simplify my task, but it still can't find the SDK.

Comment: @JustinHolbrook the files need to be in the VstsTaskSDK folder. So copy the files to the VstsTaskSDK folder (remove 0.10.0). After update, you need to update build definition in order to use the new version of task. (You can check the task version in build log whether it uses the newest version of task)

Comment: Yes I have removed the files from the folder in the SDK identified by the version number and placed them in the VstsTaskSDK folder. The new error is indicating it's looking for the files under a folder that contains the task version number.

Comment: @JustinHolbrook Do you solve this issue after update the build definition? You also can do test with a new build definition.