# Custom Extension can't find VstsTaskSdk.psd1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vsix

I'm trying to build my extension using Powershell for my Build/Release tasks for Azure DevOps. When I upload and install my extension, I keep getting the following error:

```
##[error]File not found: 'E:\ADOAgents\Agent1\_work\_tasks\MDDSVisualStudioBuild_c2ba1f80-29d5-11e7-b903-6faaecee54d3\1.0.2\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1'
```

I used the following instructions on how to build my tasks from this [tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Consuming.md#package-the-sdk-with-the-task). I have also used the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292533/tfs-vsts-custom-build-task-execution-cannot-find-vststasksdk-psd1) from StackOverflow to make sure I didn't get this error but I was never able to solve it.

Here is the file structure of my tasks:

```
package-lock.json
README.cmd
vss-extension.json
MDDSVisualStudioBuild
   -task.json
   -icon.png
   -task.loc.json
   -VSBuild.ps1
   -ps_modules
      -VstsTaskSdk
         -* (all the files)
```

This is how I build my extension:

[image: My pipeline for my extension]

```
1. use node 10.16
 2. npm install
 3. npm init -y
 4. npm install -g azure-pipelines-task-lib --save
 5. npm i -g tfx-cli
 6. tfx extension create --manifest-globs vss-extension.json --rev-version
 7. Copy *vsix Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
 8. Publish vsix Artifact: package
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The version in my vss-extension.json wasn't matched with the version in my task.json.

:( This took me forever